# Create whole dynamic form each time user clicks button add in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

No I have a form field using angular and I want to replicate whole form each time user clicks in a add button. Each new row form will be a separatly request to the server using RxJS

At the end will be a "run" button, enabled when all form info will be added.

How can I do it? Any example to follow?

Thank you very much

Comment: It can help you : https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple you just need to create array of `FormGrop` like

```
forms: FormGroup[]
```

and on add form button click you just need to add new form into that

Here is the example code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiple-dynamic-form

Example App: https://angular-multiple-dynamic-form.stackblitz.io